# Loading a default home page in WebBrowser - Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to create a page in my app which will show simple text updates, and I'm planning on using a browser window to show this, so, to put it simply I want a browser windows within the app that will only show one page, I don't want the user to be able to navigate to another site.

I've got the browser window added in XAML like so:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <phone:WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,6,0,0" Name="webBrowser1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="595" Width="438"/>
    </Grid>
```

I've then got this in the C# file:

```
private void WebBrowser_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //SaveFilesToIsoStore();
        webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.nokia.ie/"/*, UriKind.Relative*/));
    }
```

Basically, first of all, am I doing this the right way, and if so, how do I get the browser to display the web page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listen to the browser navigation and stop navigation to any sites that you haven't defined

```
private void WebBrowser_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.nokia.ie/"));
    webBrowser1.Navigating += OnNavigating;
}

private void OnNavigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    //every navigation to any sites that is not www.nokia.ie will be blocked
    if(e.Uri.OriginalString != "http://www.nokia.ie/")
    {
        e.Cancel=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, all im getting when i open view the debugger is a blank white browser window. am i meant to add anything to the XAML? First time doing anything with WebBrowser :)

Comment: the navigate call should work... anyway from xaml you can use the source property of the WebBrowser <WebBrowser Source="your site here"/>. and you have to set in the manifest the internet capabilities